# UITextView selectionRange strange behavior with plus sign "+"

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, editing

If I have a plus sign in my UITextView, and I try to set the selectionRange to immediately precede it (i.e, put the cursor before the plus sign), it automatically moves to the next space.  As far as I can tell, this is specifically for plus signs; for example, equals signs and minus signs do not exhibit this behavior.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this to Apple as a bug in iOS 4.2.  They asked me to try it in the iOS4.3 beta.  It appears to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the + sign may be messing with the phone number detection. Do you have Phone Number detection active for that UITextView? have you tried disabling it?

Comment: Never enabled it, but for good measure just tried setting dataDetectorTypes to UIDataDetectorTypeNone.  No help.